# Find a specific couple of lines of code from large git repo

Tags: git

So i remember that i once did something in another project and (later removed it), that could be useful now. Thanks to some other SO post i managed to search the repository for a half remembered string..

```
git grep halfRemeberedNameOfFunction $(git log -g --pretty=format:%h)
```

and Yay! got some results

```
2d0bcde:path/to/project/file.c: result = halfRemeberedNameOfFunction( data );
65fc672:path/to/project/file.c: result = halfRemeberedNameOfFunction( data );
24f2858:path/to/project/file.c: result = halfRemeberedNameOfFunction( data );
252e3a5:path/to/project/file.c: result = halfRemeberedNameOfFunction( data, args );
b58bc0b:path/to/project/file.c: result = _halfRemeberedNameOfFunction( data, options );
dce8d9d:path/to/project/file.c: result = halfRemeberedNameOfFunction( data, moreData );
```

But it's not enough of the surrounding code? How do i get the entire file at one of those revisions?

Many thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want what `git show 252e3a5:path/to/project/file.c` gives you?

Comment: OK, I've added an answer to that effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass the file part to git show:

```
git show 252e3a5:path/to/project/file.c
```